# Linker warnings with new Linux kernel

Tags: linux, kernel, gcc

**Thanks for the pointer to the right spot on the mailing list!**

```
  CALL    scripts/checksyscalls.sh
  CALL    scripts/atomic/check-atomics.sh
  DESCEND objtool
  CHK     include/generated/compile.h
  LD      arch/x86/boot/compressed/vmlinux
ld: warning: arch/x86/boot/compressed/efi_thunk_64.o: missing .note.GNU-stack section implies executable stack
ld: NOTE: This behaviour is deprecated and will be removed in a future version of the linker
ld: warning: arch/x86/boot/compressed/vmlinux has a LOAD segment with RWX permissions
  ZOFFSET arch/x86/boot/zoffset.h
  AS      arch/x86/boot/header.o
  LD      arch/x86/boot/setup.elf
ld: warning: arch/x86/boot/pmjump.o: missing .note.GNU-stack section implies executable stack
ld: NOTE: This behaviour is deprecated and will be removed in a future version of the linker
ld: warning: arch/x86/boot/setup.elf has a LOAD segment with RWX permissions
  OBJCOPY arch/x86/boot/setup.bin
  OBJCOPY arch/x86/boot/vmlinux.bin
  BUILD   arch/x86/boot/bzImage
Kernel: arch/x86/boot/bzImage is ready  (#4)
```

I am suddenly getting these linker errors compiling linux v5.19 from git.

My compiler and linker are:

```
nn@penguin:/usr/src/linux-5.15.71$ gcc --version 
gcc (Ubuntu 12.2.0-3ubuntu1) 12.2.0
Copyright (C) 2022 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

nn@penguin:/usr/src/linux-5.15.71$ ld --version
GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.39
Copyright (C) 2022 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This program is free software; you may redistribute it under the terms of
the GNU General Public License version 3 or (at your option) a later version.
This program has absolutely no warranty.
```

I just wanted to see if there was an obvious solution before posting to the kernel mailing list.

Comment: See here: https://lkml.org/lkml/2022/8/8/825

Comment: Erm. They are warnings **not** errors.

Comment: As a coder, when I take the trouble to have a piece of software tell you something, it is generally because I think it will matter to  you.  As  Bogart said, "Maybe not today, and maybe not tomorrow, but soon and for the rest of your life".